# SwiftUI How To Set a View's Max-Width to Phone Size vs iPad Size

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that on an iPhone I want to take up the width of the entire screen.  Which can easily be done with the code below.  But, on an iPad I want the view's width to remain phone-sized vs expand to the edge of the device.  Does anybody know how to do that?

```
struct ContentView: View{
   var body: some View{
       HStack{
          Text("Hello World")
       }
       .frame(minWidth:0,maxWidth: .infinity)
       .background(Color.red)
   }
}
```

EDIT: If anybody else finds this adding this line let me specify a size specifically for the iPad.

```
.frame(minWidth:0,maxWidth: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 500 : .infinity)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the frame depending of the device

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .phone:
        // It's an iPhone
    case .pad:
        // It's an iPad
    case .unspecified:
        // Uh, oh! What could it be?
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!   I added an if statement to the frame and it worked perfectly .frame(minWidth:0,maxWidth: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 500 : .infinity)